# Numerical approximation to Beta moment generating function

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, moment-generating-functions, expected-value

I have a Beta random variable $X \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$, and I'm interested in $\mathbb{E}[e^{2X}]$.

The Beta distribution moment generating function is

$$f(t) = {\displaystyle 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\left(\prod _{r=0}^{k-1}{\frac {\alpha +r}{\alpha +\beta +r}}\right){\frac {t^{k}}{k!}}} = {}_1F_1(\alpha, \alpha + \beta; t)$$

So I need to compute $f(2)$. But I need to do that quickly for many pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$. What is an efficient method to compute this?

Comment: Do you have access to advanced mathematical software, such as Matlab, Mathematica, etc.? Or some open software, I'm sure a lot of them have the packages for computing hypergeometric functions

Comment: @YuriyS Well, no, that's the problem. I need to implement that is Stan, which I don't think has it inbuilt.

Comment: Ok, well, in general, evaluating hypergeometric functions is not a trivial task. First, you can obviously use the series definition. Another option is to find an integral representation and use some numerical quadrature. Yet another option is to find the ODE which the function obeys and solve it numerically. The choice depends on the range of the parameters and other things... Not sure about ${_1 F_1}$, you'll just have to hit the books so to speak (like NIST library of functions, or Abramowitz and Stegun for example)

Comment: If I remember correctly, Bessel function and also Laguerre polynomials are particular cases of this function, so there has to be plenty of sources available

Comment: Let me clarify: if you are asking for an approximation, what is the desired accuracy? And what is the range of the parameters, since different approximations usually work for different ranges

Comment: @YuriyS $\alpha$ is positive real, unlikely to be very small or very large. Bounds $[0.01, 100]$ should be enough. Similarly for $\beta$, so the second parameter $\alpha + \beta$ is in $[\alpha+0.01, \alpha + 100]$. We can fix $t=2$. Error less than $0.001$ is sufficient; computation speed is more important than accuracy.

Comment: just google it, you may take a look at https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/porterm/papers/hypergeometric-final.pdf